# Add a new function to a existing jquery script

Tags: jquery, function, multi-select

I am trying to work the following solution into a jquery multiselect script, the solution is supposed to take the title of the multiselect element and display it when no item is selected, the problem is I have no idea how to modify the script to add the functionality. I basically have to solution in my hands but not sure how to put the two things together.

This is the solution :

I thought I would share this snippet with you guys.
It uses the title attribute from the select element to title the noneselecttext: option

```
<select id="id" multiple="" name="name" title="your title"  class="multiselect">    <option value="val">text</option> </select>

//Jquery Code
$('.multiselect, this).each(function(key, val){  $(this).multiselect({     noneSelectedText:''+$(this).attr('title')+''  });     });
```

I have added the multiselect class to the html form fields, im just not sure how to add the jquery part to the script below.

This is the script :

```
(function($, undefined){

  var multiselectID = 0;



  $.widget("ech.multiselect", {

      // default options
      options: {
          header: true,
          height: 175,
          minWidth: 150,
          classes: '',
          checkAllText: 'Check all',
          uncheckAllText: 'Uncheck all',
          noneSelectedText: 'Select options',
          selectedText: '# selected',
          selectedList: 0,
          show: '',
          hide: '',
          autoOpen: false,
          multiple: true,
          position: {}
      },

      _create: function(){
          var el = this.element.hide(),
              o = this.options;
```

Answer (score 0):

Job done !, in the index.php I added the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('.multiselect', this).each(function(key, val){ 
    $(this).multiselect({ 
      selectedList: 8,    
      noneSelectedText:''+$(this).attr('title')+''  });     
  });
});
```